# SQL insert value in friendship table based on

Tags: sql

I’m taking a database course and I’ve got stuck on one of the questions. “For all cases where A is friends with B, and B is friends with C, add a new friendship for the pair A and C”. 
This is as far as I’ve got

```
INSERT INTO 
    friend
SELECT DISTINCT 
    f1.ID1, f2.ID1 
FROM 
    friend f1 
    JOIN friend f2 using (ID2), 
    friend 
WHERE 
    f1.ID1 <> f2.ID1 
AND friend.ID1 <> f1.ID1 
AND friend.ID2 <> f1.ID2
```

The schema is here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cf8b5/23

I wonder if somebody could give me a few hints on how to proceed.
Thanks.

Comment: Just a tip - you should specify the columns you want to insert into on the `friend` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the basic concepts.

I'd do it like the following:

```
INSERT INTO friend
(ID1, ID2)
SELECT DISTINCT f1.ID1, f2.ID2
FROM friend f1
  INNER JOIN f2
    ON f1.ID2 = f2.ID1
      AND f1.ID1 <> f2.ID1
      AND f1.ID2 <> f2.ID2
WHERE f1.ID1 <> f2.ID2
```

Comment: The question asks for *new* friendships, so you should check that the record doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thanks Marlin, this works. But as CL pointed out, I can see that I need to get rid of duplicates. Of course the answer must contain only new friendships. Help?

Comment: Thanks guys for your input. I filtered out the duplicates with "except SELECT * FROM friend" and now it's OK.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about excluding existing records on my walk to lunch.  It occurred to me that the third join to the friend table was for that.  Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be:

```
INSERT INTO friend
(ID1, ID2)
SELECT DISTINCT h.ID, f2.ID2
FROM Highschooler h 
inner join friend f1 on(h.ID=f1.ID1) 
inner join friend f2 on(f1.ID2=f2.ID1)
where h.ID <> f2.ID2
and not exists(select *
               from friend f3
               where f3.ID1=h.ID
               and f3.ID2 = f2.ID2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see the point of having both FRIEND and LIKES tables.

If friendship is represented by two highschoolers liking each other than one table with two ID columns is sufficient.

Comment: This is not an answer; and the `Friend` table *does* have two ID columns.

Comment: Well, apparently the FRIEND table contains mutual friendships whereas the LIKES table is not reciprocal, by that I mean that person A can like somebody but that somebody does not necessarily like person A.

Comment: Does it mean that if A is friend with B and B is friend with C and A likes C BUT C doesn't like A, then A can't be friends with C ?

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into friend
select f1.id1, f2.id2
from friend f1 join friend f2 on f1.id2 = f2.id1
where f1.id1 <> f2.id2
except
select * from friend
```